# CISCO WebEx camera and mic work in browser mode but, not the app

Tags: permissions

I was able to add the applications, CISCO WebEx and Zoom, to the Microphone and Camera permission to access using TCCPlus from another thread.  The toggle button works, and it is selected on. When I access WebEx via the app and using the test site, it still does not recognize that it is allowed.  When I launch the session in browser mode using Safari I get the pop up window asking for permission and both work.

I have no issue with Zoom it works fine within the application.

I have both Ventura and OpenCore patcher running the latest version on a iMac late 2011 machine.